# ClickHouse Question For DB::Exception URL “XXX” is not allowed in config.xml

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I use the remote function to import data from remote servers in another clickhouse cluster, when I use the sql like :

```sql
INSERT INTO dataplugin.ods_stb_info_all_local 
SELECT evtTime,evtCode,pVer,sdkVer,sdkSortId,stbID,manufacturer,model,cpName,macAddress,wifiMacAddress,romVer,apkVer,accessMethod,provinceCode,cityCode,now() as writeTime 
FROM remote('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:19000','dataplugin','ods_stb_info_all','default','');
```

the error happens like this:

```
Code: 491. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: URL "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:19000" is not allowed in config.xml.
```

I really can not understand what happened, I wish for someone's helps

Answer (score 1):

It needs to define `remote_url_allow_hosts`-section in `config.xml`:

```xml
<yandex>
    <!-- The list of hosts allowed to use in URL-related storage engines and table functions.
        If this section is not present in configuration, all hosts are allowed.
    -->
    <remote_url_allow_hosts>
        <!-- Host should be specified exactly as in URL. The name is checked before DNS resolution.
            Example: "yandex.ru", "yandex.ru." and "www.yandex.ru" are different hosts.
                    If port is explicitly specified in URL, the host:port is checked as a whole.
                    If host specified here without port, any port with this host allowed.
                    "yandex.ru" -> "yandex.ru:443", "yandex.ru:80" etc. is allowed, but "yandex.ru:80" -> only "yandex.ru:80" is allowed. 
            If the host is specified as IP address, it is checked as specified in URL. Example: "[2a02:6b8:a::a]".
            If there are redirects and support for redirects is enabled, every redirect (the Location field) is checked. 
        -->

        <!-- Regular expression can be specified. RE2 engine is used for regexps.
            Regexps are not aligned: don't forget to add ^ and $. Also don't forget to escape dot (.) metacharacter
            (forgetting to do so is a common source of error).
        -->
    </remote_url_allow_hosts>
</yandex>
```

Example from test [test_allowed_url_from_config](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/tests/integration/test_allowed_url_from_config/configs/config_with_hosts.xml):

```xml
    <remote_url_allow_hosts>
        <host>host:80</host>
        <host_regexp>^[a-z]*\.ru$</host_regexp>
    </remote_url_allow_hosts>
```

---

Steps:

- open `config.xm` for editing

```sh
sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/config.xml
```

- define the required settings
  config.xml:

```xml
<yandex>
    ..
    <remote_url_allow_hosts>..</remote_url_allow_hosts>
    ..
</yandex>
```

- restart service to apply settings

```sh
sudo service clickhouse-server restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However, I noticed the tag named 'remote_url_allow_hosts', I deleted the tag and it did not work, I will find if I mistook some important steps.@vladimir

Comment: I finally figure out that why my configuration file does not work, because I do not use ``` service clickhouse-server restart ``` or ``` systemctl restart clickhouse-server ``` I just think it will reload the configuration file, What a fool, thank you very much @vladimir